# PHP regex find string with multiple values

Tags: php, regex

My question concers this string: `Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'image', $image->getFile())->resize(265)`

I'm trying to find a way to find this string. but... in the string are: $product, image and 265 variable.
So I need to find strings like:
`Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'image', $image->getFile())->resize(265)`
`Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'thumb', $image->getFile())->resize(75)`
`Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($image, 'mini', $image->getFile())->resize(25)`
etc...

For now I have this, but it just searches throug files for `Mage::helper('catalog`

```
function listFolderFiles($dir){
    $ffs = scandir($dir);
    foreach($ffs as $ff){
        if($ff != '.' && $ff != '..'){
            if(is_dir($dir.'/'.$ff)) listFolderFiles($dir.'/'.$ff);
            if(strpos($ff, '.phtml')!==false){
                $contents = file_get_contents($dir.'/'.$ff);
                $pattern = preg_quote("Mage::helper('catalog", "/");
                $pattern = "/^.*$pattern.*\$/m";
                if(preg_match_all($pattern, $contents, $matches)){
                   echo "Found matches in: ".$dir.'/'.$ff."\n";
                }
                else{
                   echo "No matches found in: ".$dir.'/'.$ff."\n";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

listFolderFiles('../app/design');
```

Comment: are you shure to use " $pattern =" and not " $pattern .=" to append the next patterns to the regex?

Comment: yes, it also works fine like this :-) I just need to extend it...

Comment: Glad to help. Is it working now? (Just a tip when using RegEx: Print it out, put it into a live-regex-box and see what it builds you!)

Comment: Hi EGORecords, It *was* already working, I need some help to find Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'image', $image->getFile())->resize(265) and not only Mage::helper('catalog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no apparent need for `"/^.*$pattern.*\$/m"`, `preg_match_all` or `$matches`

```
$pattern = "/Mage::helper\('catalog\/image'\)->init\([^)]+?image->getFile\(\)\)->resize\(\d+\)/";
if ( preg_match($pattern, $contents) ) {
    // do stuff
}
```

This will match any string containing `"Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init(Ximage->getFile())->resize(Y)"`,
where `X` is one or more characters that are not `)`, and `Y` is one or more digits.

Comment: You sir, are awesome, I can use this! your explanation was really useful.